# Is the hypotenuse of a triangle ever divisible by three (for primitive Pythagorean triples)?

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Looking for a proof that for *primitive* Pythagorean triples, the hypotenuse is never divisible by three.

Below are a list of all the primitive Pythagorean triples with a hypotenuses less than 300. None are divisible by 3.

(3, 4, 5)   (5, 12, 13)     (8, 15, 17)     (7, 24, 25)
(20, 21, 29)    (12, 35, 37)    (9, 40, 41)     (28, 45, 53)
(11, 60, 61)    (16, 63, 65)    (33, 56, 65)    (48, 55, 73)
(13, 84, 85)    (36, 77, 85)    (39, 80, 89)    (65, 72, 97)
(20, 99, 101)   (60, 91, 109)   (15, 112, 113)  (44, 117, 125)
(88, 105, 137)  (17, 144, 145)  (24, 143, 145)  (51, 140, 149)
(85, 132, 157)  (119, 120, 169)     (52, 165, 173)  (19, 180, 181)
(57, 176, 185)  (104, 153, 185)     (95, 168, 193)  (28, 195, 197)
(84, 187, 205)  (133, 156, 205)     (21, 220, 221)  (140, 171, 221)
(60, 221, 229)  (105, 208, 233)     (120, 209, 241)     (32, 255, 257)
(23, 264, 265)  (96, 247, 265)  (69, 260, 269)  (115, 252, 277)
(160, 231, 281)     (161, 240, 289)     (68, 285, 293)

So the question: is this true for all primitive Pythagorean triples?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is not relatively Prime? $9,12,15$

Comment: $C$ in a primitive triple is always of the form $4x+1,x\in\mathbb{N}$ so it is never divisible by $3$ in a primitive triple.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The hypotenuse of a primitive triple is never divisible by $3$.  For let $(x,y,z)$ be a primitive triple, and suppose $3$ divides $z$. Then $3$ cannot divide $x$ or $y$, else the triple would not be primitive.

It follows that $x^2$ and $y^2$ have remainder $1$ on division by $3$, which means $x^2+y^2$ has remainder $2$ on division by $3$.

**Remark:** A somewhat more elaborate argument shows that if $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$, then $p$ cannot divide the hypotenuse of a primitive triple.

Comment: Ah I see... If z was divisible by 3, both x and y must be divisible by 3 but then it wouldn't be a primitive triple.

Comment: Yes, that's how the argument goes. It is easy to verify that when you square a number of the form $3k+1$ or $3k+2$, you get a number of the form $3k+1$,

Comment: OK, further to that then, can only one of the legs can be divided by three?

Comment: Yes: for primitive examples the same argument says that exactly one leg is divisible by $3$

Comment: @MK345: In any triple, at least one of the legs is divisible by $3$. For if neither is then as above $x^2+y^2$  has remainder $2$ on division by $3$. But no square can have remainder $2$.  Now we could obtain the answer to your question by saying that one leg is divisible by $3$, so if the hypotenuse is then the triple cannot be primitive.

Answer (score 3):

Not significantly different but I'd write this out using the modulus. That is, numbers can be $-1, 0, 1 (\mod 3)$ and thus the squares of them can only be $0, 1$ now $0+0 \equiv 0 (\mod 3)$ so then for a primitive 3-tuple this is not possible; also $1+1 \equiv 2 \equiv - 1(\mod 3)$ and $\nexists c \in \mathbb{N}|c^2 \equiv -1(\mod 3)$. So the only possibility is $a \equiv 0, b\equiv 1, c\equiv 1$ drawing both results in one go: exactly one side is divisible by three in a primitive triple and that side is a leg.

Edit: mod 4 the situation is not different, the squares are still 0 and 1 $(\mod 4)$ and so exactly one side is divisible by four in a primitive triple and that side is a leg.

And it so happens that the smallest set, is an example when these two are different: 3,4,5 and the second 5, 12, 13 is when these two are the same. Isn't mathematics beautiful?